# How to repeat character input if the user enters the wrong one?

Tags: c

I tried this code but it's not working and I honestly don't know what is wrong here. I think that this logic would work with numbers, but that appears not to be the case with characters.

Edit: I just realised my mistake and corrected it in an answer.

```
char choice;

printf("\nAre you ready? (y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'n') {
        printf("\n\nYou can only answer with y or n!");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    }

    if(choice == 'n') {
        printf("\nYour answer was no.");
    }

    else if(choice == 'y') {
        printf("\nYour answer was yes.");
    }
```

Comment: `(choice != 'y' || choice != 'n')` is always true. You need `&&`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh shoot! I should've been more cautious. That's it. I didn't even realise there was OR instead of AND. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My bad, the logic is good, I just wrote OR `||` instead of AND `&&` in while loop.

It should be like this:

```
while(choice != 'y' && choice != 'n')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as already said in comments, `(chice != 'y' || choice != 'n')` will always be `true`. Logically, you should use `&&` instead of `||` there.

Moreover, in C when you take any input, you have an additional `\n` character added to the input byffer. Therefore, when your `while` loop runs for the first time, it doesn't read a new character, but instead it reads the `\n` from the previous input.
A way to fix that is to call `getchar()` after each `scanf` call.

Comment: Wouldn't `fflush(stdin)` do the same as `getchar()` in that case?

Comment: Well yes, but you don't have it either